# mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such deviceuse

Tags: networking, aircrack-ng

When I try to use the command `airodump-ng mon0` it returns `device not found`

How do I solve this?

```
dani@danish:~$ sudo airmon-ng start wlp12s0

Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
795 NetworkManager
808 avahi-daemon
911 avahi-daemon
994 wpa_supplicant
1133    dhclient
Process with PID 1133 (dhclient) is running on interface wlp12s0

Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlp12s0     Broadcom    wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

Comment: Um, what's your question?

Comment: bro  mon0 device not found, when i try to use cammand "airodump-ng mon0" it gives error device not found

Comment: Please [edit] your *question* to include this additional data.

Comment: what exactly u wanna know i mean im new in this thing so plz define?

Comment: First off, _don't_ use `plz`, `u`, etc. Take some time to actually be coherent. We take time to help you.

Comment: hmm, so far more time taken to correct grammar?

Comment: `wl` does not support monitor mode.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather well known that the Broadcom STA driver doesn't support monitor mode. You can confirm this yourself:

```
iw list
```

My wireless card reports:

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
```

Moreover, for almost all Broadcom devices, one and only one driver supports the device. For these, we know of no alternate driver that works at all, much less provides monitor mode.

Comment: iw list............Supported commands:
   * set_interface
   * new_key
   * join_ibss
   * set_pmksa
   * del_pmksa
   * flush_pmksa
   * connect
   * disconnect
 software interface modes (can always be added):
 interface combinations are not supported
 Device supports scan flush.

Comment: monitor mode enabled on mon0 but device not found ?

Comment: what should i exactly do?

Comment: Get a different device.

Comment: Give me any other suggestion plz

Comment: I have none other. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for this error:

1. Device is in use: Kill all processes mentioned which could cause trouble, e.g.

   `kill -9 994` (kills your `wpa_supplicant`)
2. Update to latest `airmon-ng` version: The [documentation](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng#error_add_ifacepermission_denied) suggests to update to the latest version from svn.

Comment: its updated already ive checked.
and i have tried kill but no working for me

Comment: You have to kill the five processes mentioned , if airmon-ng still warns you about them that means that they are still running.

Comment: im killing but i gives again again new process?

Comment: How to kill at once

Comment: I kiled all with Aircrack-ng check kill but still not working